# wordpress get request redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to simulate GET request for my blog here http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/SimulateUserAgent.asp.

It shows status `OK` if the browser does not have www prefix in URL whereas it gives 403 forbidden when URL has www prefix.

What can be done so that i get status as OK with URL as http://myblog.com or http://www.myblog.com ?

This is how general settings in wordpress looks like
[image]

Also i have added below code to htaccess file.

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   www to non-www
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Kindly refer below screenshot.

URL : http://myblog.com (Request Status : OK)
[image]

URL : http://www.myblog.com (Request Status : Forbidden)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Once i update the htaccess with above will the changes happen immediately or do i have to check after some time?

Comment: After I removed all the code from htaccess and just put the code you have provided its working like charm. But if I put this code in my existing htaccess it does not work as expected. Here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/pqAFseAa) for htaccess file. Let me know if you see flaw in the code.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't see where the code was in the pastebin. Did I just miss it? Or did you leave it out?

Comment: Removed `HEAD` from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]` and it worked.

Comment: @Santosh Good stuff -- I had never heard of that plugin before. You might also check out [this one](http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/rewriterule-viewer-plugin.html) just for debugging purposes... I don't think a lot of people know about it but maybe I'm wrong.